# How to get primary DNS server ip of specific domain?

Tags: dns

I thought it is possible via `nslookup`, but when I use

```
nslookup stackoverflow.com
```

it gives me different ip (**198.252.206.16**) than `whois cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com` (173.245.59.4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default record returned by `nslookup` is the A record, in this case `198.252.206.16`. You should use `nslookup` with the `querytype` flag for soa record.

```
# nslookup -querytype=soa stackexchange.com 
...
Non-authoritative answer:
stackexchange.com
    origin = cf-dns01.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: I thought the IP of DNS server is the ip from nslookup stackoverflow.com. So what is the ip i got from nslookup stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I probably don't see the difference between domain ip adress and ip address of its primary DNS server

Comment: Then you need to research more on how DNS works. It is not so complicated, a set of records for different purposes. If you don't understand those, you are banging your head on a wall. An 'A' record says where to direct http traffic, MX records are used for directing smtp traffic, and so on. It seems alot of people who study networking first, end up with weird ideas about DNS.

Comment: @Krab domain IP address = street address, IP address of its primary DNS server = address of the local post office. (That metaphor won't really stretch any further because the DNS is a very very distributed post office.)

Answer (score 2):

using `host`

```
host -t soa www.stackoverflow.com
```

output:

```
www.stackoverflow.com is an alias for stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com has SOA record cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2016653041 10000 2400 604800 3600
```

using type `NS`

```
host -t NS www.stackoverflow.com
```

output:

```
www.stackoverflow.com is an alias for stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com name server cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com name server cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to query the [Start of Authority](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/soa-record/) for the domain with `dig`:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# dig stackoverflow.com soa +short
cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2016653041 10000 2400 604800 3600
```

You can also query for all the nameservers:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# dig stackoverflow.com ns +short
cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com.
cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com.
```

Depending on what it is you're actually trying to do.